# Failed to add a object in a app in the admin panel of Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am just a beginner in Django Web Development.Following a tutorial I tried to add a object on a app by admin in Django. [This is a screenshot before adding object. After clicking Save button I got the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3446Z.png)

```
OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/product/add/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: C:\Users\royal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-                        
packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 296
Python Executable:  C:\Users\royal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\royal\\PycharmProjects\\PyShop',
'C:\\Users\\royal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
'C:\\Users\\royal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\royal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\royal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
'C:\\Users\\royal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\royal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Users\\royal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\royal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
 Server time:   Tue, 24 Mar 2020 15:59:31 +0000
```

I'm completely new in this sector.Help me to get rid off this error.

Comment: Mostly this problem occurs due to some conflicts in previous versions of migration files. If you are just learning Django then [reset current migrations](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html), delete your SQlite3 db file(which is at root of your project) and then reapply all the migrations(i.e makemigrations and migrate, creating super user etc) once again. It should solve your problem.

Comment: so, you are asking me to delete the current one and add a new ? or to overwrite the existing one?

Comment: Whenever you perform `makemigrations` some files gets created by Django. These are the files you need to delete. See this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html). And then delete `db.sqlite3` file from your project (Assuming that you have not configured any other DB like SQL,postgress etc and you are using default db i.e SQlite3). And then again perform all the migrations.